# Prevent User from checking out without email on order

Tags: commerce

I am using drupal commerce and sometimes a truly anonymous order without email comes through (phone is required so we always call when it happens, its super super rare). Is there a way to not allow the payment process button to proceed if an email hasn't been attached to anonymous cart? I use commerce login step (https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_login_step) to show a simple login page before proceeding. (BTW Email is required on account panel so I'm not sure how they get through)

With that said I made a module to try and figure this out if they get past the commerce login step :

```
$uid = 0; // anon
$product_count = 0;
$product_quantity_count = 0;

$cart = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
if($cart->uid == 0 && empty($cart->mail)){
   dsm("Hey there is no email here!");
}
```

However is there a way to add to the checkout validation hook to see if "There is no email on the order, do not allow them to checkout and process payment?"